# Grouping into intervals

Tags: sas, sas-visual-analytics

I want to create intervals under my grouping bins in SAS Visual Analysis. I Googled and found this pertinent info in the relevant section of the documentation.
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/vaug/67500/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n133d7vjj5losnn0zber8iw4vzum.htm

But apparently my interface behaves differently than the one in the documentation.

All MCC code (data-field rows) with field-values between 3501-3786 will be included into the Hotel category. But I do not see the interval option. Only the option of dragging single fields over to the groups that I have created.

PS. I have selected the ‘classic interface’ in SAS VA, to enable users to export content from the data. I don’t know if this has any bearing on the solution.

Can you please help?

Comment: What version of SAS VA do you have? Is the field a character or numeric field?

Comment: We are running the latest version of VA v. 7.4 Hotfix 2. The format shows a '$'. What is it then?

Comment: Its a character field, which doesn't lend itself to an interval option. A numeric variable would.

Comment: Thanks Reeza, I figured it out yesturday. I made a 'treatas' numeric on this field. This way I enabled the interval grouping.   :)  Write it up as a solution. And I will credit you with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a 'treatas' numeric on this calculated field. This way I enabled the interval grouping.